# Laravel Eloquent whereRaw sql clause returns all rows when using OR operator

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) i am using [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) to fetch all users associated with a group.

(It's a legacy database so it doesn't follow Laravel conventions unfortunately).

The users table has a column with a GroupId which is a Foreign Key to a Group table with the associated information on the group which the users belongs to.

I want to select all users associated with two specific groups, selected by their name. And it works when i DO NOT use an OR operator in the whereRaw clause of the SQL statement. In that case it just returns all rows, despite their names.

If i remove the OR ..., the code works as intended and returns only users associated with the GroupId i query, in this case "KO011".

('GroupId's semantic meaning is just the Groups name)

```
User::select(array('name','surname','GroupId'))->with(array('Group'=> function($q)
    {
        $q->select(array('Id','GroupId', 'GroupDescription'));

    }))->whereHas('Group', function($q)
    {
        $q->whereRaw("GroupId = 'KO11' OR GroupId = 'KO05'");
    })->get());
```

The sql log dump from when i query with the or operator is (undesired result, all rows):

```
[2014-11-28 17:12:40] local.INFO: select `name`, `surname`, `GroupId` from `Users` where (select count(*) from `Group` where `Users`.`GroupId` = `Group`.`Id` and GroupdId = 'KO11' or GroupId = 'KO05') >= 1 {"bindings":[],"time":182.84,"name":"dbname"} []
[2014-11-28 17:12:40] local.INFO: select `Id`, `GroupId`, `GroupDescription` from `Group` where `Group`.`Id` in (0, 12, 28, 9, 3, 32, 4, 2, 1, 16, 31, 13, 18, 10, 33, 29, 5, 11, 8, 21, 19, 20, 14, 30, 25, 22, 6, 23, 7, 15, 48, 17, 26, 24, 157, 52, 27, 51, 47, 50, 158, 134, 104, 105, 106, 118, 154, 103, 96, 107, 101, 108, 146, 102, 109, 100, 98, 99, 97, 95, 174, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 149, 183, 110, 184, 170, 111, 150, 114, 138, 113, 112, 159, 145, 121, 115, 140, 176, 117, 147, 135, 116, 139, 155, 148, 169, 164, 165, 166, 161, 185, 168, 172, 177, 167, 178, 180, 179, 191, 173, 193, 188, 175, 192, 187) {"bindings":[0,12,28,9,3,32,4,2,1,16,31,13,18,10,33,29,5,11,8,21,19,20,14,30,25,22,6,23,7,15,48,17,26,24,157,52,27,51,47,50,158,134,104,105,106,118,154,103,96,107,101,108,146,102,109,100,98,99,97,95,174,94,93,92,91,90,89,88,87,86,85,84,149,183,110,184,170,111,150,114,138,113,112,159,145,121,115,140,176,117,147,135,116,139,155,148,169,164,165,166,161,185,168,172,177,167,178,180,179,191,173,193,188,175,192,187],"time":55.44,"name":"dbname"} []
```

and when i only query with one group (correct results):

```
[2014-11-28 17:57:26] local.INFO: select `name`, `surname`, `GroupId` from `Users` where (select count(*) from `Group` where `Users`.`GroupId` = `Group`.`Id` and GroupId = 'KO11') >= 1 {"bindings":[],"time":93.18,"name":"dbname"} []
[2014-11-28 17:57:26] local.INFO: select `Id`, `GroupId`, `GroupDescription` from `Group` where `Group`.`Id` in (3) {"bindings":[3],"time":405.02,"name":"dbname"} []
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must nest these `wheres`, also why do you want that `whereRaw` there?

```
->whereHas('Group', function($q)
{
    $q->where(function ($q) {
       $q->where('GroupId', 'KO11')->orWhere('GroupId', 'KO05');
    });
})
```

Because `whereHas` adds something like `where fk = ? and ...`.

Other way would be:

```
$q->whereRaw("(GroupId = 'KO11' OR GroupId = 'KO05')")
```

Comment: Hi, your second proposal worked! The first one returns all rows. I should have added that i had already tried the nested solution. Thats why i tried to use whereRaw, albeit with the wrong syntax. - Thanks a bunch!

Comment: 1st works as well, it produces exactly the same `(.. or ..)` piece. Make sure you're doing it right.

Comment: Ah, off course. I forgot to place the query inside the callback! Gotta get new glasses..